# Upload files using ajax in MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've been trying to upload a file async using ajax as I need to keep a lot of elements in my page so I can't really afford to refresh the page without putting inputted values back.

```
//clear data
            elements = [];

            //get current data
            var files = $('input[type=file]');
            var formData = new FormData();
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
                if (files[i].files.length > 0)
                {
                    elements.push(files[i].name);
                    formData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                }

$.ajax({
                    url: "/Monitoring/UploadFiles",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,                    
                    processData: false, // Don't process the files
                    contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
                });
```

This is what I tried so far but I'm not getting any files in my controller method. I do get something in `Request.Form` but it's a string with the value `"[HTMLInputElement"]`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Content-Type must be multipart/form-data if you are uploading a file.

Comment: @RoyDictus i've set `contentType: "multipart/form-data"` and now it's not even registering in the request keys

Comment: Check this out: http://davidsonsousa.net/en/post/how-to-upload-a-file-using-mvc-3-and-ajax